# How do i get only the "dd" from a date cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a  list of dates shown like this "1/1/2015" and/or "23/12/2015".
I would like to place a function in another column, in which I will have only the "dd" value from the date.

ex. for 1/1/2015 I would like to have the result "1" and for the 23/12/2015 the result "23"

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula, supposing the date is in cell A1:

```
 =DAY(A1)
```